# How to set up a secure connection between Filbeat and Elasticsearch using SSL

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm unable to setup an SSL connection between Filebeat and Elasticsearch.

My knowledge is lacking when it comes to SSL. I'm using X-Pack to generate a certificate using the `certutil` command.  `bin/xpack/certutil ca` generates a certificate authority under the name `elastic-stack-ca.p12`.

Then

```
$ bin/x-pack/certutil cert --ca elastic-stack-ca.p12
```

Which I believe creates a certificate signed by that CA. This results in the file `elastic-certificates.p12`. From here I'm clueless.

I tried testing to see if the certificates work by setting up a HTTPS connection to ES.

I put

```
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.key:  /path/to/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /path/to/elastic-certificates.p12 
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: [ "/path/to/elastic-stack-ca.p12" ]
```

However, this brings up quite a few errors one of them being

```
caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection
```

When I add the `https` IP and the CA in Kibana it fails to connect with ES.

I would like to know how to successfully set up https. Also how can a SSL connection be established between two servers. One containing Filebeat, but no X-Pack and the receiving server with ES on it alongside X-Pack installed.

Answer (score 2):

After adding those SSL settings in your `elasticsearch.yml`, you also need to add the password to the Elasticsearch keystore and truststore. You should've set a password when you ran the `certutil` command. You can do that with:

```
$ echo password | /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password
$ echo password | /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password
```

Make sure you restart Elasticsearch after making these changes.